# Java 2d array Hourglass Sums challenge from Hackerrank

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, array

This is a java solution to [a Hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array).

I know it's not optimized, can anyone help me to refactor and optimize?

> **Task**:
>
> Calculate the hourglass sum for every hourglass in the 6×6 array, then print the maximum hourglass sum.
>
> An "hourglass sum" is defined as the sum of any 7 entries of the array that are selected by this pattern mask:
>
> ```
> ✓ ✓ ✓
>   ✓
> ✓ ✓ ✓
> ```
>
> **Input Format**:
>
> There are 6 lines of input, where each line contains 6 space-separated
>   integers describing 2D Array; every entry is in the inclusive range -9 to 9.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print the largest (maximum) hourglass sum found in the array.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 1 0 0 0 0
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 0 2 4 4 0
> 0 0 0 2 0 0
> 0 0 1 2 4 0
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 19
> ```

Solution:

```
public class TestHourGlass {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                int arr[][] = new int[6][6]; 
                int hourGlassSum[] = new int[16];
                int pos = 0;

                //Reads data from user input and store in 6*6 Array
                for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++) {
                    for (int arr_j = 0; arr_j < 6; arr_j++) {
                        arr[arr_i][arr_j] = in.nextInt();
                    }
                }
                //Find each possible hourGlass and calculate sum of each hourGlass
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        hourGlassSum[pos] = calculateHourGlassSum(arr, i, i + 2, j, j + 2);
                        pos++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(findmax(hourGlassSum));

            }
            /**
             * @param arr 
             * @param pos1 - Row startPoint
             * @param pos2 - Row endPoint
             * @param pos3 - column startPoint
             * @param pos4 - column endPoint
             * @return
             */
            public static int calculateHourGlassSum(int arr[][], int pos1, int pos2, int pos3, int pos4) {

                int sum = 0;
                int exclRowNum = pos1 + 1;
                int exclColNum1 = pos3;
                int exclColNum2 = pos4;
                for (int arr_i = pos1; arr_i <= pos2; arr_i++) {
                    for (int arr_j = pos3; arr_j <= pos4; arr_j++) {
                        sum = sum + arr[arr_i][arr_j];
                    }
                }
                sum = sum - (arr[exclRowNum][exclColNum1] + arr[exclRowNum][exclColNum2]);
                return sum;
            }

            /**
             * @param arr
             * @return max elem of Array
             */
            public static int findmax(int arr[]) {
                int max = arr[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    if (arr[i] >= max)
                        max = arr[i];
                }
                return max;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Avoid magic number

6 and 16 should be replace with properly named constants... 16 is also dependant of the first number ; if I'm not mistaken the number of possible hourglasses is (6 - 2)²

```
public static final int GRID_SIZE = 6;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_HOURGLASSES = Math.pow(GRID_SIZE - 2, 2);
```

### Better naming

Most of your variable have good name, however it's not useful to name indices *arr_i* and *arr_j*, name them simply *i* and *j*.

The class name is not that good IMO, `HourGlassSolver` or `HourGlassFinder` would be better.

`findmax` should be cased like this `findMax`

Parameters for calculateHourGlassSum have unclear name (pos2 ??)

### Simplify your function

Your function do their jobs well but can be made shorter thanks to the new Java 8 Stream API.

For example, your findmax :

```
public static int findMax(final int arr[]) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).max().get();
}
```

### Extract part of your code into a function

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       hourGlassSum[pos] = calculateHourGlassSum(arr, i, i + 2, j, j + 2);
       pos++;
   }
}
```

This should probably be made into a distinct function that returns an int array or a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need an array to store all the sums? You could just keep track of the maximum sum since that is what you're going to return in the end.

```
int max = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE-2; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE-2; col++){
        int temp = hourGlassSum(arr, row, col);
        max = Math.max(temp, max);
    }
}
System.out.println(max);
```

---

I also agree with Angela but I would reason about the top left corner instead from the middle:

```
public static int hourGlassSum (int[][] arr, int row, int col){
    return    arr[row][col]   + arr[row][col+1]   + arr[row][col+2]
                              + arr[row+1][col+1] 
            + arr[row+2][col] + arr[row+2][col+1] + arr[row+2][col+2];
}
```

which my editor sadly auto indents back to

```
public static int hourGlassSum(int[][] arr, int row, int col) {
    return arr[row][col] + arr[row][col + 1] + arr[row][col + 2]
            + arr[row + 1][col + 1]
            + arr[row + 2][col] + arr[row + 2][col + 1] + arr[row + 2][col + 2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Imus..No need of an array here..your logic works...

Answer (score 2):

for a grid that's 6X6. Like @Ronan mentioned, there are (6-2)^2 number of hourglass because if you look at the center of the hour glass, at position `d`. It's only valid from position at (1,1) to (4,4).

So in the main function, you can first scanner the digits and store in an int arr[][].

Then from (1,1) to (4,4), I call the below function:

```
public static int hourGlassSum (int[][] arr, int row, int col){
    int sum = arr[row][col]+ arr[row-1][col-1]+ arr[row-1][col]+ arr[row-1][col+1]
        + arr[row+1][col-1]+arr[row+1][col]+ arr[row+1][col+1];
    return sum;
}
```

Notice how int row and int col from the above function is the position of the center of the hourglass, position `d` in the graph. in my personal opinion, this is easier to understand than your `calculateHourGlassSum()`